# if any subject got "F" or "0", then Total Grade I want to show = "F"

Tags: php, sqlite

I attached my output image here: [this my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4GjQ.png)

```
    <table width="100%" style="text-align:center">
            <tr>
                <td>Subject </td>
                <td>Grade </td>
            </tr>  
    <?php

        include 'connect.php';
        $class_n =$_POST['class_n'];
        $class_s =$_POST['class_s'];
        $r =$_POST['roll'];

        $sql="select * from full_result where class_n='$class_n' AND class_s='$class_s' AND roll='$r'";
        $data = mysql_query($sql);
        $sum=0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
        {
        $r=$row['marks'];
        if($r>=40)
        {
        $r1=$row['point'];
        }
        elseif($r<=33) 
        {
        $r1=0;
        }
        $sum=$sum+$r1;
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['grade']; ?> </td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['point']; ?> </td>
            </tr>

    <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <br>
        <p><?php echo $sum;  
            ?> </p>
```

This my code, here I am trying to use one condition, but it's doesn't work. it comes almost total Marks. But what I want  is that when any subject becomes 0 or F, the Total mark will become F.

Comment: Can't understand what you are trying to do, and what goes wrong. Can you show a precise exemple of "what is actually displayed" and "what I want to be displayed" ?

Comment: Yes, Pls see this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag variable and set it to 1 if the student get 0 or F (I assume it's when `$r <= 33`) for any subject. Then before displaying sum, check if the flag is set and if set change value of `$sum` to '`F`'

```
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center">
        <tr>
            <td>Subject </td>
            <td>Grade </td>
        </tr>  
<?php

    include 'connect.php';
    $class_n =$_POST['class_n'];
    $class_s =$_POST['class_s'];
    $r =$_POST['roll'];
    $flag = 0;

    $sql="select * from full_result where class_n='$class_n' AND class_s='$class_s' AND roll='$r'";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
    $sum=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    {
    $r=$row['marks'];
    if($r>=40)
    {
    $r1=$row['point'];
    }
    elseif($r<=33) 
    {
    $r1=0;
    $flag = 1;
    }

    $sum=$sum+$r1;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['grade']; ?> </td>
             <td><?php echo $row['point']; ?> </td>
        </tr>

<?php } 
    if($flag == 1)
    {
      $sum = F;
    }
?>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p><?php echo $sum; ?> 
        ?> </p>
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. Please accept the answer if it worked. :)